# LINQ-to-Entities: Conditional loading of nested lists

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have an object with the following hierarchy

```
class Account
   string username
   List Delegations

class Delegation
   List SingleDelegations

class SingleDelegation
   string uid
```

Now I'd like to perform a query which loads an `Account` object with the according dependencies (i.e. Delegations and Delegations.SingleDelegations) already loaded (with that single query), **but** it should just load those matching a specified condition, namely

- only those accounts where the username matches a parameter (easy)
- only those `SingleDelegation` objects where the uid matches a given parameter

**My Approach**
I have the following method in my `AccountRepository`

```
public Account ReadAccountsByUsernameAndUid(string username, string uid)
{ 
    var matchingObjs = (from a in context.Accounts
                            from d in a.Delegations
                            from sd in d.SingleDelegations
                            where
                               a.username == username &&
                               sd.uid == uid
                            select new 
                            {
                               Account = a,
                               Delegation = d,
                               SingleDelegation = sd
                            });

     //knowing there should be just one account (ignore the missing null check for now)
    return matchingObjs.FirstOrDefault<Account>().Account;          
}
```

This obviously returns an anonymous type object having the different objects exposed as properties. Since the `Account` and `Delegation` and `SingleDelegation` are linked over corresponding FKs my `Account` object will have them properly loaded (as the context knows them).

Personally, this looks weird. I have to create a new anonymous type for instructing EF to include the subobjects in the query s.t. in the end I get my `Account` object properly loaded.

**My Question:**
Is there a better, nicer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no better or nicer way. This is how EF works. If you want to filter relations and retrieve all data with single query you must always use projection.